# How come bootstrap.min.css looks like commented

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, minify

When I get minified version of Bootstrap v3.2.0. to me it seems like it's commented, but it is working, what kind of comments are those, how browser understands it:

```
/*!
* Bootstrap v3.3.6 (http://getbootstrap.com)
* Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
* Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
*//*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css      */html{font-fami
```

Look here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: its not, it has `*/` on the same line just before the start of html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further, the `/*!` preserves the comment through the minify process.

Answer (score 2):

The slash asterisk, `/*`, opens a multi-line comment and `*/` closes multi-line comments. You can see right before the CSS starts the comment is closed by the `*/`.

Comment: So blind, didn't notice it's terminated comment. Thanks for pointing it out